# Proper Way to Instantiate Subclass/Lib in Singleton Class

Tags: c++, oop, object, arduino

I have a working example, however, I'm not sure I am doing this correctly.  I am using an Arduino Lib to handle a [circular buffer](https://github.com/rlogiacco/CircularBuffer) in this case, and I'd like to wrap it in a Singleton class within my project since I will interact with the class in many places within the project.

Here's my MRE:

main.cpp:

```cpp
void loop() {
    Buffer *myBuffer = Buffer::getInstance();
    Ticker bufUpdate;
    bufUpdate.attach(1, [myBuffer](){ myBuffer->update(); });
    while (true) {
        yield();
    }
}
```

buffer.h:

```cpp
class Buffer {
    private:
        // Singleton Declarations
        static Buffer *single;
        Buffer() {}
        // Other Declarations
        int randVal();
        void start();
        CircularBuffer<float, 400> samples;

    public:
        // Singleton Declarations
        static Buffer* getInstance();
        ~Buffer() {single = NULL;};
        // Other Declarations
        void update();
};
```

and buffer.cpp:

```cpp
Buffer* Buffer::single = NULL;

Buffer* Buffer::getInstance() {
    if (!single) {
        single = new Buffer();
        single->start();
    }
    return single;
}

int Buffer::randVal() {
    return random(0, 254);
}

void Buffer::update() {
    int value = single->randVal();
    samples.push(value);

    // Do other stuff here ...
}
```

This is operating as expected, but I am not sure it's correct.  My experience so far in this project is my "roots" may look fine but later on, I realize I had a flaw so that's why I'm looking for assistance.

Comment: In the code it is just declaring an unused local variable. What do you think it's doing?

Comment: Well, I can see that "samples" is being used as a circular buffer (you can see the `samples.push(value);` line), so it does not seem to be acting local.  I would have expected to have to address it as `single->samples` but that does not appear to be valid.  Like I said, "seems to work" and "did it right" are obviously not the same thing.

Comment: You have 2 `samples`. One private member in the `Buffer` class. One unused local variable in the `start()` method. The one in `start()` is redundant and should be deleted. Not sure if that answers your question or not...

Comment: It does actually - half of it anyway.  Is the declaration in the header the proper method to achieve this?  Have edited the original code per your comments for clarity.

Comment: You don't need `instanceFlag` - just use `single` having a value or not as the flag.`getInstance` should just be `if (single == 0) { single = new Buffer() } return single;`

Comment: Thanks, @John3136 for helping optimize my method of creating a singleton. Part of the original question remains, however - is the header the proper place to be instantiating that subclass?

Comment: Instantiate what subclass? All you have is a class definition... No subclass anywhere in your code. I'd suggest you need to do some more study. Either your knowledge is lacking or the terminology you are using to try to describe the issue is non standard.